# Jenkins, Ubuntu node and slaves build failing to save the items to temp folder

Tags: unix, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

Here is my code and error text :

```
export PUBLIC_HOSTNAME=”$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname 2>/dev/null)”
wget https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/archive/master.zip
unzip -o master.zip
cd ./Rocket.Chat-master
meteor build –server $PUBLIC_HOSTNAME –directory .
cd ./bundle/programs/server
npm install
cd ../..


2018-06-30 09:09:07 (3.90 MB/s) - ‘master.zip’ saved [6681014]
+ unzip -o master.zip
/tmp/jenkins6836919479896690199.sh: 12: /tmp/jenkins6836919479896690199.sh: 
unzip: not found         
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

So its failing to unzip the files downloaded.

can someone put me in right direction?

---

error:

Comment: Your scripts seems to `cd` around quite a bit. Are you sure you are in the correct place relative to which `master.zip` is searched for?

Comment: after adding command to install unzip, its able to unzip. how ever I stuck at the next line   
**bold**  + meteor build –server ”ec2-35-176-163-9.euwest2.compute.amazonaws.com” –directory .
    /tmp/jenkins9094619843987962056.sh: 15: /tmp/jenkins9094619843987962056.sh: meteor: not found
    Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE **bold**

Comment: now meteor installed using curl, still its unfinished:                                                                          + meteor build –server ”ec2-35-176-163-9.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com” –directory .
build: too many arguments.
Usage: meteor build <output path> [--debug] [--directory] [--server-only]
          [--mobile-settings settings.json] [--server http://example.com:3000]

Answer (score 0):

Either utilities (unzip, meteor) are not installed on you jenkins servers (master/slave) or $PATH varibale is not set properly.

If utilities are installed please include utilities path in ENV PATH variable. Please let me know if you need help on that.

Comment: Thankyou, I added code to install utilities and working good, as I am running the code from demo , I encounter these issues however herewith its giving error with main code:   <code> + meteor build –server ”ec2-35-176-163-9.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com” –directory . <code>

build: too many arguments.
Usage: meteor build <output path> [--debug] [--directory] [--server-only]
          [--mobile-settings settings.json] [--server http://example.com:3000]